# Multiple IF AND Statements with 6 possible outputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to set up an excel formula containing multiple IF(AND statements. I tried this:

```
=IF(AND(C9="0",C8="65"),Tables!B6,
 IF(AND(C9="0",C8="70 to 75 depending on which bank"),Tables!C6,
 IF(AND(C9="1",C8="65"),Tables!D6,
 IF(AND(C9="1",C8="70 to 75 depending on which bank"), Tables!E6,
 IF(AND(C9="2 or More",C8="65"), Tables!F6,
 IF(AND(C9="2 or More",C8="70 to 75 depending on which bank"), Tables!G6, "NULL"))))))
```

and all I got was "NULL". Not sure how to fix this.

Here is a visualization of what I'm trying to do, with 6 possible outputs depending on the conditions met:
[image: Photo of what I am trying to do]

Comment: Sorry, can't see the picture.  Are the numbers in `C9` naturally aligned to the left or right (i.e. with no alignment set do they appear to the left or right)?  If they're right aligned then remove the quotes from the numbers as Excel is treating them like numbers and the formula is treating them as text - `C9="0"` is different from `C9=0`.

Comment: Also check the spaces in the cells - `"70 to 75 depending on which bank"` or `"70 to 75 depending on which bank "` (extra spaces on end of text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookup table, like this:

```
0&65    A
0&75    B
1&65    C
1&75    D
2&65    E
2&75    F
```

If your lookup table is in `A1:B6` then your formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(C9&"&"&C8,$A$1:$B$6,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula. You had to nest another AND inside AND formula to apply condition `from 70 to 75`.  No need for helper column.

```
=IF(AND(C9=0,C8=65),Tables!B6,IF(AND(C9=0,AND(C8>=70,C8<=75)),Tables!C6,IF(AND(C9=1,C8=65),Tables!D6,IF(AND(C9=1,AND(C8>=70,C8<=75)),Tables!E6,IF(AND(C9>=2,C8=65),Tables!F6,IF(AND(C9>=2,AND(C8>=70,C8<=75)),"F","NULL"))))))
```